# Cannot create UIToolBar in code

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode6

Swift wont let me create a toolbar in code in Xcode 6.1. Declaring a UIToolBar in my Swift code i get the undeclared type error:

> Use of undeclared type 'UIToolBar'

Please note the following points:
- '!' and '?' in various places had no effect

- Tried declaring it as a variable (var) or a constant (let)
- In the same project, i have created custom views, table view cells etc
- The file is included in the project target
- Tried to declare it as an @IBOutlet

Please check the attached screenshot.
What am i doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be `UIToolbar` not UIToolBar

```
var toolbar: UIToolbar
```

Comment: Not very stupid, UITabBar and UIToolbar? How am I supposed to know they're different?

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the toolbar and inherit from UItoolBar if you need custom toolbar.

You can then override the drawRect: method or layoutSubViews function as per need. If you are creating the UIToolbar add it as a subview.

use this -

```
let toolbar = UIToolbar()
toolbar.sizeToFit()
toolbar.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```